# Owl carousel is not working in internet explorer version 8

Tags: internet-explorer, owl-carousel

I am using Owl Carousel in my website.

This slider is working for all browsers except IE8 (below IE9 version).

Comment: Please give more details, such as the code snippet, if you want others to help you. Also, state clearly what exactly do you mean by 'not working' (i.e. it doesn't run? any error message?).

Comment: Hello billy,
It does not work with ie 8. 
i am using "http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html" this slider for my website. This slider is works with all browsers except ie8 or below ie versions 9.

Answer (score -1):

In owl.carousel.js file, go to line 1377 to find these :

```
base.clearEvents();
base.$elem.attr({
    style: base.$elem.data("owl-originalStyles") || "",
    class: base.$elem.data("owl-originalClasses")
});
```

Change those to this :

```
base.clearEvents();
base.$elem.attr({
    "style": base.$elem.data("owl-originalStyles") || "",
    "class": base.$elem.data("owl-originalClasses")
});
```

Based on the limited information you've provided, it's probably related to [this IE8 issue](https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/pull/317/files).

Comment: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html

This is the link. Could you please check this link with ie8

Comment: The script file in the link you provided (owl.carousel.js) uses the code without `"`. That's what caused that page not work on IE8. If you have used a different script, then you should have posted the code snippet / link to your page instead of wasting others' time.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "doesn't work" because when I checked yours on IE8 emulator (using IE11, I don't have IE8 anymore), yours does work flawlessly whereas the original demo doesn't work. The only difference is that the 3 slider navigation buttons are in square instead of round because IE8 doesn't support border radius, and that's all.